# How to make my seagate external hard drive write on a Mac, even if it is compatible with both windows and Mac?

Tags: windows, external-hard-drive, macbook, macbook-pro

I have a Seagate external hard drive.  When I first installed it I made it compatible with both Windows and Mac even though I, myself, have a Macbook Pro.

For some reason it works very well with Windows, it reads and writes to Windows but when I connect it to any Mac it only reads the drive but I cannot write (give or take any data from Mac).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "When I first installed it I made it compatible"? How did you format/partition it? One or multiple partitions? What kind, ext, FAT or NTFS?

Answer (score 1):

Your disk is probably formatted as NTFS. Windows can read and write NTFS, but Macs can only read it. Formatting it as exFAT or FAT would allow you to read and write on Windows and Mac.

An alternative to reformatting the drive would be to add NTFS support to your Mac, either [with 3rd party software](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/ntfs-mac/), or by essentially [editing /etc/fstab](http://osxdaily.com/2013/10/02/enable-ntfs-write-support-mac-os-x/) to mount the volume with the 'rw' option.

Comment: You may want to stay "safe" as forcing a mount point to be "rw" could have fairly catastrophic results if the OS doesn't have native support for a competitor FS...